# How to create a Google Reader?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, feed, google-reader

I need to create a web tool like Google Reader for my college project.

I have 2 question about it:

**1)** How Google Reader track the read and unread posts ?

**2)** Google Reader save every post in the db or load the feeds at the moment ?

Comment: by "college project", I think the whole idea was for you to think this through and implement a design of your own make, not copy from already existing systems.

Comment: was the project to make stackoverflow already taken?

Comment: @Richard Neil Ilagan: It's hard to come up with a truly original idea that makes sense; OTOH, reinventing a complex enough wheel will teach you *a lot*. A feed reader is a pretty intricate system, even though it doesn't appear that way on the surface.

Comment: @Piskvor ~ touche. makes much more sense when you put it that way. +1

Answer (score 3):

1. assign a hash to a single feed post (ie. date+url+??? = hash to identify a single post)
2. loads them on the fly would be my guess, maybe caches a limited number per user.

Comment: so Google Reader save the hashes in the database ?

Comment: that's the way it probably works. Remember, this is just my interpretation of the frontend and the behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

re #2: Google has a special RSS crawler bot called [FeedFetcher](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178852). When you request the RSS feed, it's dispatched to retrieve it, and stores the feed into its global (all-user) cache, identified by URL. Next time the feed is requested (even by a different user - as long as the URL matches), it is loaded from the cache.

I'm not sure what the cache invalidation mechanisms are, but the crawler definitely doesn't revisit the feeds strictly as often as the response's `Cache-Control` mechanisms would indicate (that's probably a good thing, as many generated RSS feeds send `no-cache` although they don't change too often). This internal cache doesn't seem to persist for longer than a few hours, though.

(these are the hypotheses I formulated some time ago from my RSS feed access logs; I still think they're valid, as I haven't seen any major change in the crawler's behavior since)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it may help now, but for others who drop by I jotted my thoughts with a detailed design:

[Designing a Scalable Google Reader Clone](http://blog.sangupta.com/2011/02/designing-scalable-google-reader-clone.html)

Answer (score 0):

You car use **[Selfoos](https://github.com/SSilence/selfoss)** the new multipurpose rss reader, live stream, mashup, aggregation web application.

**Features:**

- web based rss reader
- universal aggregator
- open source and free
- easy extendable with an open plugin system (write your own data
  connectors)
- mobile support (Android, iOS, iPad)
- use selfoss to live stream and collect all your posts, tweets, feeds
  in one place
- lightweight PHP application with less than 2 MB
- supports MySQL, PostgreSQL and Sqlite Databases
- OPML Import
- easy installation: upload and run
- with restful json api

**Web site**: http://selfoss.aditu.de/

**GitHub**: https://github.com/SSilence/selfoss